# Is there room for discussion/debate about the topic of your SE? And if so where should you discuss?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So specifically I am curious about this hypothetical -> Healthcare Industry is live and I would like to discuss with other professionals "How or what should/could the industry do to improve billing?" Clearly this will be opinion statements so it does not fit the normal scope of Q&A. But if a group of us wanted to discuss something like that, where would we turn to?

Comment: Forums, newsgroups, chat, mailing lists... pubs & restaurants are pretty good settings for this too.

Comment: That sounds like an ideal topic for a chat room.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags Is there a way to limit chat room access to specific people? or by a reputation score you set? or perhaps an activity level?

Comment: @Kirill I'm pretty sure it's possible to create invitation-only chat rooms. You should be able to do so as the chat room owner

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags thanks you can put yours as an answer, I'll wait a little see what else I get but this looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: Done - I found a helpful link, see below.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like an ideal topic for a chat room.

> Is there a way to limit chat room access to specific people? or by a reputation score you set? or perhaps an activity level?

It's possible [to create invitation-only chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms) for users with 1000+ rep. You should be able to do so as the chat room owner.