# Let users post Query Questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

I suggest new mechanism called Query Questions (to prevent getting put on hold as too broad):

1. Members should be given 10 Query Questions a year.
2. Query question will still have to be reviewed and approved first before posted.
3. If question has been already solved it will not get posted and result in a loss of 1 query question.
4. Query questions will only be posted 5 day max.
5. Query question with less than 10 views after 48 hours will be removed automatically for lack of interest.

> Newton's_Query_31
>
> Frame 5
>
> In 1704, Isaac Newton published the first edition of Opticks: or a Treatise of the Reflections, Refractions, Inflections, and Colours of Light. To avoid Robert Hooke's criticism of his work, Newton waited until the death of Hooke in 1703 to release his work Opticks to the public. The Royal Society forbid theoretical science (that not based on experiments) so Newton put forward his theories in the form of queries. These queries present his ideas in the form of questions, not formal hypotheses which were rejected by the Baconian school of reasoning. One particular query, Number 31, was particularly significant for chemistry. He discussed the known fact that particles interacted with each other, but sought a formula to explain the interaction.

([source](https://classesv2.yale.edu/wiki/site/chem124_f08/newton%27s_query_31.html))

Comment: You have failed to demonstrate how your suggestion is better for the community than the current status of affairs.

Comment: There already is a section for posting query questions. It's called the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. What is a *query question*?

Comment: @Pat I've tried to edit based on what I understand after 5 times reading. Still lacking some details, but at least makes some sense now.

Comment: @MrCruz what's the point of this? Users won't be able to downvote or close Query questions? Anything else?

Comment: Helping someone get one step closer to there solution or even answering it for them is a act of kindness and I thought that was the purpose.

Comment: This suggestion would be improved with a definition of a "Query Question" (seems tautologous) and possibly an example of one.

Comment: @Mr.Cruz sorry but your comment makes 0 sense. Probably language barrier, so guess we can't really communicate. Too bad.

Comment: What **is** a query question?

Comment: I put rules and structure to this opinion and It is not the same as the query chat option.. Members would put more thought into there Post due to only 10 query questions allowed. Plus it would be a place for answers or suggestions only, If you cant post a solution or a suggestion with the intention to help then don't post anything at all. The community would see less sarcasm and negative replies and that would benefit Stack Exchange.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of your edit? I am a little confused...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there room for discussion/debate about the topic of your SE? And if so where should you discuss?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137750/is-there-room-for-discussion-debate-about-the-topic-of-your-se-and-if-so-where)

Answer (score 12):

It seems to me you are proposing a way to circumvent the current rules (aka closing questions or putting them on hold). This is not a good idea!

Rules are there for a reason. We honestly believe that some questions are too broad to be answered. We would love to give an answer, but we can't. It would take tons of text or code to answer the question, which isn't the purpose of the site.

We *help* people by closing questions: if the question gets improved we *can* give a proper and useful answer. Until then it helps the community not to spend time on questions that can't be answered.

The answer to anything to circumvent this: ***NO!***

Comment: The reason I posted this suggestion is because there are too many Robert Hook's on this site that show the ugliness in man kind and post mean and sarcastic replies and that is worser that the stupid question a person could ask.

Comment: So instead of fixing that issue (as you say 'mean and sarcastic replies') we have to create more problems?